# ¿Como Devolver datos de distintos modelos desde Nodejs y MongoDD?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Buenas a todos, Tengo una aplicación web hecha en Nodejs, en una de las peticiones debo de enviar datos de distintos modelos. Mi consulta es la siguiente ¿Esta es la manera correcta?

```
function getProduct (req, res) {
  let productId = req.params.productId
  Product.findById(productId, (err, product) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})
    if (!product) return res.status(404).send({message: `No existen productos`})
    Company.find({}, (err, companies) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})
      if (!companies) return res.status(404).send({message: `No existen compañias`})
      res.status(200).send({product: product, companies: companies})
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Esta es la manera correcta?

No. Hay un error con ese código y es que, **respondes dos veces a una sola petición**. Lo que debes hacer es, guardar en un objeto los documentos de cada colección que iteras y, en el último callback, enviar tu respuesta.

**Nota:** para evitar un [*callback hell*](http://callbackhell.com/) te recomiendo usar [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa).

```
function getProduct (req, res) {
  let productId = req.params.productId

  Product
    .findById(productId)
    .then((product) => {
      Company
        .find()
        .then((companies) => {
          res.jsonp({
            product,
            companies
          });
        })
        .catch(handleError.bind(this, res));
    })
    .catch(handleError.bind(this, res));
}

function handleError (res, e) {
  res
    .status(500)
    .jsonp({
      errors: [
        message: 'Ha ocurrido un error. Intente más tarde',
        detail: e.message
      ]
    });
}
```

Y en el cliente, por ejemplo si estás haciendo una API la consumes con AJAX:

```
fetch (`/products/${productId}`)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      res.json().then(({ product, companies }) => {
        // hacer algo con product y companies
      });
    } else {
      res.json().then(({ errors }) => {
        // manejar los errores
      });
    }
  });
```